# How to get list of non-zero variables in scip

Tags: python, scip

I'm using pyscipopt to use scip and in my model I want to look at those columns of a matrix that correspond to the variables that are non-zero. However the expression `A[:, np.nonzero(var_list)[0]]` doesn't work as expected because the objects in the list `var_list` are variable objects, not their respective values, so they are all considered to be non-zero. How can I get around this?

Edit: This expression is in the objective I am trying to minimize, so something like `[Model.getVal(x) for x in var_list]` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new list only containing the values of `var_list`

```
new_list = [var.value for var in var_list]  # List containing the values
A[:, np.nonzero(new_list)[0]]
```

Comment: I should clarify: This expression is in the objective I want to minimize, so I don't have the values yet at that point